# cvQueryFrame() returns NULL before end of file

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm trying to process large AVI files (approx. 61000 frames, 505MB) with 
OpenCV, using `cvCaptureFromAVI()` and `cvQueryFrame()`.

However, `cvQueryFrame()` returns a `NULL` pointer before it reaches the last frame 
of the avi.

```
long int numframe = 6000;
while (numframe < 67000)
{        
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if (! frame)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not query the frame %ld.\n", numframe);
        break;
    }

    char namefile[250];
    sprintf( namefile, "/media/6E86F8CB03A4DFA4/image-sequence/%ld.jpg", numframe );
    cvSaveImage( namefile, frame ); // save frame as a image

    numframe++;
}
```

Has anyone else has had the same problem and found a way around it? 
Is there something that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are experienced one of the FFMPEG integration bugs. [This bugreport](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1223) looks very similar to your problem.

What version of OpenCV are you using?

Any way I recommend you:

1. Try another version of OpenCV
2. Try to build OpenCV without FFMPEG. Probably OpenCV will be able to read your file with VfW or GStreamer.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1. 

It's exactly the same problem reported. I will try OpenCV 2.2 because he said in the bug report that he experienced problems with 2.3, 2.3.1 and 2.3.2, but not with OpenCV 2.2.

Thank you for your answer!